# npm-request doesnt go to fiddler

Tags: node.js, fiddler, node-request

My POST request doesn't go to Fiddler, even though I specified a proxy url:

```js
router.get('/', function (req, res) {

console.log("in /api/");
 request(
        {
            method: "POST",
            uri: "http://api(...)'", //I cut the real url
            proxy: "http://127.0.0.1:8888" // 
        },
        function (err, response, body) {
           // console.log(response);
            res.send(response); // this gives me a real response
        });

});
```

Note: my url: http://node.dev:8080/api is pointing to localhost.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just realised this was an issue on my side with fiddler. I needed to change the fiddler setting to show all processes, not just web browser.